# How do I prevent this <button> from leaving the borders of its parent <div>?

Tags: html, button, css-float, border

I'm running into a weird issue when trying to float a button to the right;

Un-floated:

[No float http://puu.sh/3Afx1.png](http://puu.sh/3Afx1.png)

Floated right (I want it to appear in the bottom right hand corner, but still within bounds):

[Floated right http://puu.sh/3AfzF.png](http://puu.sh/3AfzF.png)

HTML:

```
                <div class="portlet box red modify-menus-page-portlet">
                        <div class="portlet-title">
                            <div class="caption"><i class="icon-external-link"></i>Custom URL</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="portlet-body" style="display: block;">
                        Add a menu link to a custom URL.
                        <br>
                        <br>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter custom text..." class="m-wrap span12">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter custom URL..." class="m-wrap span12">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <button style="float:right;" class="btn red add-menu-link-button">Add <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i></button>
                        </div>
                </div>
```

CSS:

```
.modify-menus-page-portlet {
  margin-left: 24px;
}

.portlet.box.red {
border: 1px solid #ef8476;
border-top: 0;
}

.portlet.box {
padding: 0px !important;
}

.modify-menus-page-portlet {
margin-left: 24px;
}

.portlet {
clear: both;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 25px;
padding: 0px;
}

.portlet.box .portlet-body {
background-color: #fff;
padding: 10px;
}
.portlet-body {
clear: both;
padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `overflow:auto` to your `.modify-menus-page-portlet` rules:

```
.modify-menus-page-portlet {
    margin-left: 24px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: I did that and it only half worked: it's now staying within its div, but it added a strange red bar on the bottom: http://puu.sh/3AfLx.png Not sure where that's coming from

Comment: Please modify this fiddle so we're seeing the same thing: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/PELzy/